# JUnit testing for saveCSV

Tags: java, junit

I am new to JUnit testing and I want to write a test for saving CSV file. Since the method does not have a return value, I want to test whether the data is saved in csv file successfully. Does anyone know how to test it?
My class is :

```
private static final String COMMA_DELIMITER = ",";
private static final String NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR = "\n";
private String file_position;

public SaveCSV(String file_position){
    this.file_position = file_position;
    File file = new File(file_position);
    file.mkdir();
}

public void savePlayer(HashMap<Integer, Player> Player_HASH) {
    String fileName = file_position+"player.csv";
    String FILE_HEADER = "id,name,color,order" + NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR;

    FileWriter fileWriter = null;

    try {
        fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName);
        fileWriter.append(FILE_HEADER.toString());

        for(Player player : Player_HASH.values()){
            fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(player.getID()));
            fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
            fileWriter.append(player.getName());
            fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
            fileWriter.append(player.getColor().toString());
            fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
            fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(player.getOrder()));
            fileWriter.append(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error in CsvFIleWriter!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            fileWriter.flush();
            fileWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error while flushing/closing fileWriter!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The straight-forward way to test this would be to run the code and the read the output. I would first suggest changing `SaveCSV` to take in a `File` (which is more type-safe than a `String`) and to not create the directory in the constructor (since doing work in a constructor is problematic):

```
public SaveCsv {
  private final File file;

  public SaveCsv(File file){
    this.file = file
  }

  public void savePlayer(Map<Integer, Player> playerHash) {
    if (!file.exists()) {
      file.mkdir();
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Then you can test it like this:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class SaveCsvTest {
  @Rule
  public TemporaryFolder testFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

  @Test
  public void savePlayerShouldWriteCsv() {
    File file = testFolder.newFolder("folder");
    SaveCsv saveCsv = new SaveCsv(file);
    InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(
        stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    // compare contents of data
  }
```

If you want to avoid writing to an actual file in your test, I would suggest having the constructor of `SaveCsv` use Guava's [`CharSink`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/CharSink.html) class.

*Edit:* Also, `savePlayer` could be made simpler by using [try with resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).